# Storing a specific address into a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012

I'm still familiarizing myself with pointers,and thought I'd write a simple program that changes the value of money in a game,after getting the address for said value using a cheat engine.

How do I store a specific address inside a pointer? Here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* ptr = 0x00B7CE50;
    *ptr = 400;

}
```

When I try this I get the following error:

**a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int *"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast an integer to a pointer if that is supported by your C++ implementation with `reinterpret_cast` (*conditionally-supported* according to the standard). What the semantics of that are is implementation-defined and I don't know the exact behavior of Visual-C++:

```
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x00B7CE50);
```

It is definitively not going to work if you don't have permission to write to that address or if the address is from the virtual memory space of another process that isn't mapped into the current process.

Comment: Program compiles fine but then crashes when executed,so clearly this is not an address I can write to,I'll need to do more research about permissions,but my original question have been answered,so thank you for that!

Comment: Understood,it makes sense for that specific value to be an illegal memory location,I'll learn more about memory management when I get there,this was just a simple experiment.